# Facebook Canvas (web) Game for Desktop & Mobile Browsers

Tags: architecture, html-canvas, web, facebook

as the title suggests - I am about to develop a game for FB canvas.
Will the game support mobile and desktop or do I have to create two different project/game setups for this?

thanks

Comment: Using HTML5, if you make your game for mobile (first), it'll work on a mobile. Just listen to touch events as well as clicks and support small displays.